# Are the reaction wheels' spin rate (their angular momentum) initialized before launch?

Tags: orbital-mechanics

It would seem that there should be an inertial reference frame established before launch by imparting a known spin rate to each reaction wheel while the rocket is on the launch pad.

Comment: Why does a reaction wheel require an inertial frame to be established ? Are you referring to the gyroscopes in the [IMU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inertial_measurement_unit) ? They are distinct from reaction wheels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Terminology: usually the term "*reaction wheel*" is used for a wheel whose mean speed is zero. When a wheel has a permanent bias, e.g. is spun up to a couple of thousand rpm, it is called a "*momentum wheel*". Sometimes the same wheel can be operated in both modes.

The question appears to be addressing the momentum wheel mode. Typically wheels for satellites are not spun, and perhaps locked, prior to launch as they are not needed.

Wheel spin-up really needs the satellite to have acquired some sense of its pointing, or pointing rates. At that time a control loop will be needed to hold the pointing whilst the wheel is spun up against some external torque such as a thruster.